# Material that changes solubility when electric potential is applied

Tags: electrostatics, material-science

I am looking for a material witch is easy to deposit in thin films and which changes its solubility if a electric potential is applied.

Do you know of any such materials ?

EDIT: This is for what I need it.
I have a Si Substrate on which there is sputtered SiO2.
Then I have the material (to be found) and then a Si on top. Some parts of the Si are connected electronically to the bottom Si and create a electric potential. The orange material underneath the top "electrodes" should be removed. The aim is to remove the "orange" material underneath the top "electrodes" but keep it where the Si is not connected to the bottom electrode.

[image]

[image]

How could you do this ?

EDIT2: Alternativly, I could also try to heat the material underneath the electrode due with Joule heating.

(please igore the spelling error in the bottom electrode. It should be "connected")

Comment: The electric field is not going to be just directly beneath the "Connected Si" as you have suggested by your arrows. There will be a significant electric field not only directly beneath the "Connected Si" but also farther away in the lateral directions. Even if you found a material having electric field induced solubility, you wouldn't be able to create sharp, precise patterns in it using this approach. Same basic problem with using joule heating.  There will be spread in the lateral directions. Difficult to beat optical lithography when it comes to making precise, fine-scale patterns.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Thank you very much for your comment. In fact, the "cut" does not have to be so preceise. I changed my image. The material is already structured. I just want to get ridd of it underneath specific Si "electrodes".

Comment: Should the remaining orange material be insulating or conducting?

Comment: @Svavil It can be either. preferably isolating, but it is not a "must".